# Fazer DIV ocupar remanescente da página com CSS

Tags: css, css3, div

Bom pessoal, tenho uma `div#x` que varia seu `width` entre `70px ~ 220px`.
Preciso que uma segunda `div#y`,  que está ao seu lado ocupe o resto do espaço da página.

Com jQuery seria algo tipo: `$('#y).width() = 100% - $('#x).width();`.

Alguém sabe algum modo de fazer isso nas `CSS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `display:table` e `display:table-cell` para poder manipular da forma como está querendo.

**Exemplo:**

```css
.principal {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

.principal div{    
    display:table-cell;
    height:200px;
}

.principal div:first-child{background:red;width:200px;}
.principal div:last-child{background:green;}
```

```html
<div class='principal'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

No JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xyuv7ues/

Comment: Resposta muito boa @Orion, completinha, obrigado ^^